# groupByKey and distinct VS combineByKey

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, distinct

I'm learning Spark and playing around with some "exercises".

At some point, I have a JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> which contains duplicates. My goal is to group by keys and remove the duplicates.

I see (at least) two possibilities:

1. Use distinct() and groupByKey()
2. Use combineByKey() and make sure that we only add elements we didn't have before (for example the result could be a JavaPairRDD<Integer, Set<Integer>>

I used the second approach (to avoid doing a shuffle with the distinct()) but then saw the original "solution" is the first one.

Which solution is the most efficient in your opinion?